# In Grails, how can I slurp a number with leading zeroes as decimal

Tags: json, grails

```
String number = "{'number':000645}"
net.sf.json.groovy.JsonSlurper slurper = new net.sf.json.groovy.JsonSlurper()
def resource = slurper.parseText(number)
System.out.println(resource.number)
```

The result of the above code is 421 and not 645. I know that the number is being interpreted as octal. Is there anyway to specify to ignore the leading zeroes and interpret it as a decimal?

I could have a pre-processing step which removes the leading zeroes before passing it to the slurper, but wanted to see if there is a more elegant solution.

I am using grails 1.3.7.

Comment: I reproduced this issue as stated in the question.

Comment: I poured over http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/ to see if it was possible to strip the leading zeroes from the JSON as it was bein processed and I could not find a way to do it. Perhaps EzMorph http://ezmorph.sourceforge.net/ may provide a way to strip the zeroes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass in the number quoted.  what you're seeing is groovy's behavior in coercing that value to a String value.

to demonstrate, try

```
String number = "000645"
```

vs.

```
String number = 000645
```

in groovy console.  (source for your slurper is here, if you'd like to trace what's going on: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sf.json-lib/json-lib/2.4/net/sf/json/groovy/JsonSlurper.java)

Comment: If I put in quotes, then it works as expected. But since this is a number, the clients are sending it without quotes and it has to be handled.

Comment: I don't see an immediate way to change groovy's handling.  I suspect the conversion of Integer to String is via Integer constructor, but I don't have the Groovy source handy.  Since you are accepting input, you're probabably aware of all expected fields and their types.  you could pre-process, as you've said, via regex or something, or postprocess on the JSON objects.

Comment: (well, FWIW, I retract my supposition that it's via the Integer constructor.)

Comment: technically, "leading zeros are not allowed" in JSON numbers, BTW.  see http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt?number=4627 and http://json.org/.

Comment: Thanks Brian for the note from the spec. I missed that part.